# Gorm attempting to alter foreign key

Tags: go, database-migration, go-gorm

I've been using GORM's automigrate function to maintain my database tables, but I've been running into issues with GORM trying to alter foreign keys. In this specific case, GORM is trying to change a database column from an int to a bigint.

Using MySQL 5.7, Go 1.19, and GORM 1.24.5 (which based on docs may be an early version of GORM v2).

This type

```
type AggregatorCode struct {
    Id           int    `gorm:"primary_key:id"`
    AggregatorId int    `json:"aggregator_id"`
    MappedCode   string `json:"mapped_code"`
    MappedName   string `json:"mapped_name"`
}
```

belongs to

```
type Aggregator struct {
    Id             int                               `gorm:"primary_key:id"`
    Name           string                            `json:"name"`
    Description    string                            `json:"description"`
    AggregatorCode []aggregator_codes.AggregatorCode `gorm:"ForeignKey:aggregator_id"`
    CreatedAt      time.Time
}
```

I'm trying to stop it from altering the AggregatorId field, as I'm getting this error.

```
/go/app/db_migrations/migrations.go:38 Error 1832 (HY000): Cannot change column 'aggregator_id': used in a foreign key constraint 'aggregator_codes_ibfk_1'
[14.431ms] [rows:0] ALTER TABLE `aggregator_codes` MODIFY COLUMN `aggregator_id` bigint
```

I've so far tried adding tags or changing the type on the struct, all to no success.

```
AggregatorId int `gorm:"type:int" json:"aggregator_id"`
OR
AggregatorId int `gorm:"type:int32" json:"aggregator_id"`
OR
AggregatorId int32 `gorm:"type:int32" json:"aggregator_id"`
```

If anyone has advice that would be really great.

Comment: please check the answer and let me know if you face any issue

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue simply make `Id` field in `Aggregator` model and `AggregatorId` field in `AggregatorCode` model to type `int32` or `uint32`

```
type Aggregator struct {
    Id int32    `gorm:"primary_key:id"`
    ....
}
```

```
type AggregatorCode struct {
    ...
    AggregatorId int32    `json:"aggregator_id"`
    ...
}
```